# point cloud projection to image plane

Tags: photogrammetry

I have a wide range of point cloud files and images in the same area（The photos are JPEG）. So both of them involve geo-referencing, so I want to project the point cloud back to the camera plane and how do I do that?

I used DJI L1 sensor to obtain a large area of point cloud (.las.pliply. PCD) and a large number of images (.jpg). Both point cloud and image have latitude and longitude coordinates, and I want to extract the corresponding point cloud of each image for the verification of photogrammetry method. I can currently import.ply in Blender with the origin at (0,0,0). But I don't know how to project the point cloud onto the image plane, because the coordinate system in Blender is not a latitude and longitude coordinate system. Here are my point cloud files and image files.https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dJib0Oo0sm822Pfb5xeeP1HcEWdTUMcp?usp=sharing

Comment: Can we get some images to show what exactly you are trying to accomplish. I work a lot with point clouds so I may be able to help if I get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: I used DJI L1 sensor to obtain a large area of point cloud (.las.pliply. PCD) and a large number of images (.jpg). Both point cloud and image have latitude and longitude coordinates, and I want to extract the corresponding point cloud of each image for the verification of photogrammetry method.

I can currently import.ply in Blender with the origin at (0,0,0). But I don't know how to project the point cloud onto the image plane, because the coordinate system in Blender is not a latitude and longitude coordinate system.
Here are my point cloud files and image files.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dJib0Oo0sm822Pfb5xeeP1HcEWdTUMcp?usp=sharing)

Comment: @RebeccaC Hi. Could you factor those details into the question by editing it with the [edit] button, rather than post it in the comments? Thanks

Comment: If you convert that .las into CSV for me I have a script to plot them out.